# Why use Async HTTP post Android

Tags: java, android

I currently have this running in my app. The use of this is for users to send me simple messages. A dialog is opened where they can type then when they click send button I want another dialog opened saying processing and finally one opened saying thanks if successful.

Is the only / best way to do this by using asyncTask? And is there a good example/walkthrough anywhere for implementing this as I understand the theory, but not really implementation.

```
public void postData() {
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mysite.com/script.php");

    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", messageval));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }    
}
```

Comment: See following link for it. http://masl.cis.gvsu.edu/2010/04/05/android-code-sample-asynchronous-http-connections/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely need to run the network code off the UI thread. AsyncTask is a convenient way to do it, but you can roll your own threading method if you like. There's nothing magical about AsyncTask; it's just there as a convenience.

In either case, if you need to interact with the UI from the networking thread, you'll generally have to use a Handler.

Comment: THank you. Do you know of any good walkthroughs as it is the implementation i will struggle with.

Comment: The article [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) provides a good introduction to the topic, with pointers to several examples of more complex uses.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your UI thread 'hang' while data is uploded then: yes.
AsyncTask is the best way to create new thread is such situations, because it provides convinient tools to publish progress and indicate that operation is completed.